# Finding a substring that is enclosed withing double quotes in java

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing, substring

**My code :**

```
  String content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <svg width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <!-- Generator: Sketch 64 (93537) - https://sketch.com -->
        <title>Group 36 Copy 4</title>
        <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
        <g id="Portal" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="Group-36-Copy-4" fill="#FFFFFF">
                <path d="M0,7.162 L6,8.877 L6.00036056,9 C6.00036056,10.0543618 6.81623835,10.9181651 7.85109822,10.9945143 L8.00036056,11 C9.10493006,11 10.0003606,10.1045695 10.0003606,9 L10.0003606,9 L10.0003606,8.98076197 L16,7.266 L16.0003606,14 C16.0003606,15.1045695 15.1049301,16 14.0003606,16 L2.00036056,16 C0.895791064,16 0.000360563943,15.1045695 0.000360563943,14 L0,7.162 Z M14.0003606,4 C15.1049301,4 16.0003606,4.8954305 16.0003606,6 L16,6.226 L9.99950581,7.94095939 C9.96827529,6.8636983 9.0851817,6 8.00036056,6 C6.94978154,6 6.08839609,6.81003398 6.00669844,7.83960773 L0,6.122 L0.000360563943,6 C0.000360563943,4.8954305 0.895791064,4 2.00036056,4 L14.0003606,4 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
                <rect id="Rectangle" x="7.00036056" y="7" width="2" height="3" rx="1"></rect>
                <path d="M10.0003606,0 C11.0547224,0 11.9185257,0.815877791 11.9948748,1.85073766 L12.0003606,2 L12.0003606,4 L10.0003606,4 L10.0003606,2 L6.00036056,2 L6.00036056,4 L4.00036056,4 L4.00036056,2 C4.00036056,0.945638205 4.81623835,0.0818348781 5.85109822,0.00548573643 L6.00036056,0 L10.0003606,0 Z" id="Path-21" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>'
```

I have a string named "content" in java which holds any svg file's content that the user uploads. Now my task is to replace the value that is inside this attribute fill="#FFFFFF" with the input that my user has given.

**Example** : user input : `ff0000`
so now content string must replace this line `<g id="Group-36-Copy-4" fill="#FFFFFF">` as `<g id="Group-36-Copy-4" fill="#ff0000">`

I am stucked. Please help.

Comment: Hi if you working on some project better to parse xml change value and then return xml ...https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xml_parsers.htm. or you just want to replace substring????

Comment: if you only want to replace substring then use replace function , read here https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-replace-substring-in-java.html

Comment: I guess I have to give xml parsing one shot. Because that's the only way left to generalize my answer to the problem.

Comment: try this and if after that you ffeel any problem ask again.

Comment: try this example, it is clearly explained https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stax-xml-parser-java/

Comment: They have set the variable in the start as "false". I get it. But I don't know how many tags I am going to have in my xml file. Then how I am supposed to define variables? Also, would it be fine if I skip declaring of variables and do not check if they are currently in use?

Answer (score 0):

if the fill you mention in the content never change, you can use the replace function.

content = content.replace("#FFFFFF",input)

Reference : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace

Comment: Yes. Fill value changes. I took it just to explain the question. But the fact is I don't know about what will be the fill's value. It will depend on what type of svg file user is uploading.

Comment: you may parse that string

Comment: Can I achieve this by using DOM parser? Because in my project I have seen at various places that DOM is been used.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is not compilable, because you are using single quote which is for character type, you need to use double quotes for your String and escape all internal double quotes:

```
String content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><svg width=\"16px\" height=\"16px\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\" version=\"1.1\"xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"><!-- Generator: Sketch 64 (93537) - https://sketch.com --><title>Group 36 Copy 4</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc><g id=\"Portal\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"none\" fill-rule=\"evenodd\"><g id=\"Group-36-Copy-4\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\"><path d=\"M0,7.162 L6,8.877 L6.00036056,9 C6.00036056,10.0543618 6.81623835,10.9181651 7.85109822,10.9945143 L8.00036056,11 C9.10493006,11 10.0003606,10.1045695 10.0003606,9 L10.0003606,9 L10.0003606,8.98076197 L16,7.266 L16.0003606,14 C16.0003606,15.1045695 15.1049301,16 14.0003606,16 L2.00036056,16 C0.895791064,16 0.000360563943,15.1045695 0.000360563943,14 L0,7.162 Z M14.0003606,4 C15.1049301,4 16.0003606,4.8954305 16.0003606,6 L16,6.226 L9.99950581,7.94095939 C9.96827529,6.8636983 9.0851817,6 8.00036056,6 C6.94978154,6 6.08839609,6.81003398 6.00669844,7.83960773 L0,6.122 L0.000360563943,6 C0.000360563943,4.8954305 0.895791064,4 2.00036056,4 L14.0003606,4 Z\" id=\"Combined-Shape\"></path><rect id=\"Rectangle\" x=\"7.00036056\" y=\"7\" width=\"2\" height=\"3\" rx=\"1\"></rect><path d=\"M10.0003606,0 C11.0547224,0 11.9185257,0.815877791 11.9948748,1.85073766 L12.0003606,2 L12.0003606,4 L10.0003606,4 L10.0003606,2 L6.00036056,2 L6.00036056,4 L4.00036056,4 L4.00036056,2 C4.00036056,0.945638205 4.81623835,0.0818348781 5.85109822,0.00548573643 L6.00036056,0 L10.0003606,0 Z\" id=\"Path-21\" fill-rule=\"nonzero\"></path></g></g></svg>";
```

then you can use String's replace:

```
content = content.replace("fill=\"#FFFFFF\"", String.format("fill=\"%s\"", replacement));
```

this, in case you want to replace in the same variable, use a different one otherwise.

Comment: User is uploading svg file and Everytime the content will change but all I know is that fill attribute of the second <g> tag will remain but it's value will still be unknown. That's why I asked that I want to extract the value between double quotes, whatever it is. So that I can replace it with the user provided value.